# Exception while Deserialize avro data using ConfluentSchemaRegistry?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am new to flink and Kafka. I am trying to deserialize avro data using Confluent Schema registry. I have already installed flink and Kafka on ec2 machine. Also, the "test" topic has been created before running code.

Code Path: https://gist.github.com/mandar2174/5dc13350b296abf127b92d0697c320f2

The code does the following operation as part of implementation:

```
1) Create a flink DataStream object using a list of user element. (User class is avro generated class)
2) Write the Datastream source to Kafka using AvroSerializationSchema.
3) Read the data from Kafka using ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema by reading the schema from Confluent Schema registry.
```

Command to run flink executable jar:

```
./bin/flink run -c com.streaming.example.ConfluentSchemaRegistryExample /opt/flink-1.7.2/kafka-flink-stream-processing-assembly-0.1.jar
```

Exception while running code:

```
java.io.IOException: Unknown data format. Magic number does not match
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.registry.confluent.ConfluentSchemaRegistryCoder.readSchema(ConfluentSchemaRegistryCoder.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.RegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.deserialize(RegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KeyedDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:44)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:665)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Avro schema which I am using for User class is as below:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "namespace": "com.streaming.example",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "favorite_number",
      "type": [
        "int",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "favorite_color",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone point out what steps I am missing as part of deserializing avro data using confluent Kafka schema registry?

Answer (score 1):

How you wrote the Avro data needs to use the Registry as well in order for the deserializer that depends on it to work.

[But this is an open PR in Flink, still](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/6259) for adding a `ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema` class

The workaround, I believe would be to use  `AvroDeserializationSchema`, which does not depend on the Registry.

If you did want to use the Registry in the producer code, then you'd have to do so outside of Flink until that PR is merged.

Comment: Does my understanding is correct "I can not use AvroSerializationSchema directly with ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema because both serialization and deserialization should refer confluent schema registry"?. Do you have any reference example code which I can refer to use schema registry in producer code?

Comment: Right. From what I can tell, the Flink Avro serializer doesn't use the Registry, so the Avro schema would be embedded as part of each message. The plain Java producer examples can be seen here https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_tutorial.html#java-producers

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I will try to refer sample code and test both serialization and deserialization using confluent Schema registry. I update my result once tested.